# Spring Boot , Log user id in db who created specific department?

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

so in complex databases whenever something new is being created in database everything is logged in db table, Suppose we have Users table (entity we use spring data jpa) and Department table in db, in Department table we have columns and one of them is CREATE_USER_ID (which probably logs who created that department this column logs ids of users) so whenever authorized user will send create department request with specific dto fieleds my buisness logic should handle and somehow get that users id and then save in database, how am i be able to do that (i am using spring data jpa)

Answer (score 1):

You have to design your tables based on your needs like this

For example:
Your Users Table be like bellow

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Users {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(....)
private Long id;

private String name

private String lastName;

// another fields
}
```

And your Department table must be like :

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Department {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(....)
private Long id;

private string deparmentName;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(value = "CREATE_USER_ID")
private User user;

// another fields 
}
```

This database design means that every department has one user who has created this department and every user can creat many departments if is authorized

```
public interface DepatmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Deparment , Long> {

}
```

this is your DepartmentRepository for saving Department

```
public class DepartmentService {

private final DepartmentRepository repository;

 public DepartmentService(DepartmentRepository repository){
 this.repository = repository;
}

public Department save(Department department) {
 return repository.save( department);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to auutomatically store the logged in user as the CREATE_USER_ID on the department table when a user creates a department, you will have to utilize the auditing auto configuration provided by jpa

you can do this by using the annotaion @EnableJpaAuditing in your appication class

then in your department entity annote the create_user_id with @CreatedBy

This will automatically pick the logged in user id from the security context and set the value as your CREATE_USER_ID